# what keyboard shortcut is to comment/uncomment for this script tag in sublime

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext3

I have script tag in my code, what keyboard shortcut is to comment/uncomment for this script tag in sublime.

After selecting script open and close tag.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

I am pressing `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `/` and getting this

```
/*<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>*/
```

Also I pressed `Ctrl` + `/` and got this

```
// <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript">
// </script>
```

Instead of

```
<!-- <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script> -->
```

Script open and close tag are in two lines not in one line and not have any spaces too.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

For mac,high light those lines which you want to comment. hold 'command and / ' will be commented.

For windows: high line or select those lines ,then hold **ctrl + /**

If it does not work:

Go to 'edit' and see 'Comment' option to check what is your setting.

Comment: I just checked and found its 'Ctrl + /' for toggle comment and 'Ctrl + Shift + /' for toggle block comment. And I am using the same. I update more info in my question please see.

Answer (score 0):

There is a easy way to accomplish if you have time shortage, but not perfect solution to your question

Steps:
Just bring the cursor on the `script` tag line and hit `Ctrl` + `/` two times immediately.

Before

`<script type="text/javascript"></script>`

After

`<!-- // <script type="text/javascript"></script>-->`

Comment: Bad luck its not working, actually script open and close tag are in two lines not in one line and not have any spaces too.

Comment: Don't separate that script tag by enter ie two lines, keep the whole tag in one line, And then try

Comment: It already working with giving space or keeping in one line with one space before. If the problem I have currently is limitation in sublime then I will change in all my project files. Thanks for your help